# How to bundle node project into one file

Tags: node.js, bundle, babeljs

Is there any **WORKING** way how to bundle node project into one single file (including dependencies) and how?

I am using babel (`.babelrc`)

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "module-resolver",
            {
                "root": [
                    "./src"
                ],
                "alias": {
                    "test": "./test",
                    "underscore": "lodash"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: to get a better idea... can you show us a sample or a git repo of your project?.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is no.  babel can not do what you want by itself. It is a tool for transforming one dialect of Javascript into another, based on rules defined in your `.babelrc` file.  It is a compiler, not a linker (to borrow terms from the C world).

Using `babel-plugin-module-resolver` will not cause babel to transpile dependencies as if they were source files.  It is simply a babel rule which [modifies the paths](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#description) passed to `require()` or `import`.

To include dependencies as well as source files you need to use both a compiler like babel and a bundler such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/).